# Is Prettier really needed when using Eslint?

Tags: eslint, prettier

I really don't see any reason to install Prettier to my already pretty codebase, thanks to Eslint and the `eslint:recommended` extension. Not only it feels useless, but sometimes when you install Prettier on top of Eslint, its configs conflict with that of Eslint. Forcing you to install packages like: `eslint-config-prettier`

What does Prettier provide that Eslint will never do?

Comment: There are some explanations listed [here](https://github.com/prettier/prettier-eslint/issues/101). Personally, I only use prettier on the rare occasions when I'm using minified files or files with one-liner issues. For everything else I use eslint by itself.

Answer (score 0):

*Tl;dr*: you don't "need" to, but in current versions of ESLint, you'll need either a separate formatter *(recommended)* or third-party lint plugin to enforce formatting.

---

There are two kinds of tools in play here that are structurally different and better at different tasks. Speaking to how these tools work in the web ecosystem:

- **Formatters** generally only apply changes to code trivia/whitespace that don't impact runtime, such as tabs vs. spaces or when to insert newlines. They run very quickly because they don't have to deal with code logic and can reformat each file in one pass.
- **Linters** generally run a set of discrete rules that can understand code logic. They can be very powerful and change logic for the better, but are slower because lint rules have to think more (especially when you enable more advanced features such as [typescript-eslint's linting with type information](https://typescript-eslint.io/linting/typed-linting)) and re-run if any fixes are applied automatically.

The line used to be more blurry because ESLint used to provide and recommend rules that enforced formatting. This was nice because you could use one tool for both formatting and linting - and because each lint rule is configurable, you could customize your formatting preferences very granularly.

However, because lint rules each deal with a unique area of logic and all have to be re-run if any fix is auto-applied, formatting with a linter is notoriously slow, prone to missed edge cases, and difficult for the lint teams to work with. Most lint teams now recommend against using a *linter* for *formatting*:

- ESLint: [Deprecation of formatting rules](https://eslint.org/blog/2023/10/deprecating-formatting-rules)
- typescript-eslint: [What About Formatting?](https://typescript-eslint.io/linting/troubleshooting/formatting)

As mentioned at the end of both posts, if you really prefer to use ESLint for formatting, you can use the [eslint.style](https://eslint.style) plugin. It provides lint rules that enforce formatting preferences.