# Is prettier redundant when using eslint + airbnb

Tags: eslint, prettier, eslint-config-airbnb

This is a continuation of [Is Prettier really needed when using Eslint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61990915/is-prettier-really-needed-when-using-eslint)

My understanding is that historically eslint was primarily used for code quality issues and design patterns, things that impact how the code is consumed by the Javascript engine. In contrast, Prettier was used for things that are purely stylistic. However looking at the capabilities of eslint, especially when using the Airbnb style guide, it appears as though all stylistic issues are covered.

What, if any, rules might Prettier cover that are not covered by eslint (+Airbnb)?